# 'Hello World' in SAS with a macro gives syntax error

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am extremely new to the SAS world so naturally I was trying to write my 'Hello World'. Here is my MWE which gives me the syntax errors:

```
/* SAS Hello World Program */

    /*Macro with date*/
    %Macro datum;
    Title "Hello World, today is &Sysday, &Sysdate";
    %Mend datum;

    /*Create Hello World Data Set */     
    data HelloWorld;
    msg = %datum ;
    run;

    /*Print Hello World*/
    proc print data = HelloWorld;
    run;
```

It does not print the 'Hello Wolrd'-message instead it gives a syntax error which I don't understand. In the **Log** the message appears, so in principle it works - just the print step doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need the macro or title statement. In this case you would use `%let msg = "Hello World, today is &Sysday, &Sysdate";` and in the data step use `msg = &msg;`.

Comment: "extremely new to the SAS world" -- avoid macro for now.  Learn the DATA Step foundational Procs, and BY group processing.  Then highly recommend reading introductory material on macros instead just winging it.  Tons of great conference papers, try searching https://www.lexjansen.com/search/searchresults.php?q=macros%20for%20beginners

Comment: There's a SAS courses available on coursera as well. https://www.coursera.org/specializations/sas-programming

Comment: @Reeza sounds interesting! Did you complete the course?

Comment: @user190080 it's an introductory level course, introduced this year. I've been using SAS for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro you created generates a TITLE statement. So it should work fine.

But your program is using it in the wrong place.  Once your macro runs and finishes generating the text of the TITLE statement your data step will look like this:

```
data HelloWorld;
  msg = Title "Hello World, today is Thursday, 10JAN19"; ;
run;
```

Which will obviously give an error since the right side of the assignment statement now has two tokens, a variable named TITLE and a string constant, without any operator between them.  The extra semi-colon will just generate an extra null statement and not cause any problems.

Perhaps you want to create a macro VARIABLE instead of an actual macro?

To do that your program would look more like this.

```
%let msg=Hello World, today is &Sysday, &Sysdate ;

data HelloWorld;
  msg = "&msg." ;
run;
```

So when the macro variable reference is replaced this will evaluate to this SAS code to run.

```
data HelloWorld;
  msg = "Hello World, today is Thursday, 10JAN19" ;
run;
```

Notice how you use `&` to trigger the evaluation of a macro variable.  Also notice how I did not add the quotes to the value of the macro variable, but included them in the SAS code that was generated by using the value of macro variable.

NOTE that it has yesterday's day of the week and date.  That is because the automatic macro variables `SYSDAY` and `SYSDATE` are set when SAS starts running and I ran this code in a SAS session that I started yesterday.

Comment: Thx, very helpful! I wasn't aware of the difference between a macro and a macro variable in SAS and just gave it a shot. The problem then was that I really couldn't make any sense out of the SAS Log file. Would it be possible to exchange the quotes from the assignment of the variable to the call (can't test it right now) or is this syntactically impossible?

Comment: To the macro processor the quotes are part of the value. To SAS code the quotes are needed for the parser to distinguish between a string value, a variable name or number. The macro processor does not need that since it is just looking for `&` and `%` triggers. As long as you end up generating valid SAS code you can put the quotes anywhere. Just don't get confused and think that the macro processor will remove the quotes for you the way it appears that the SAS code does.

Comment: You can use the `MPRINT` option to have SAS show the code that a macro generates. And the `SYMBOLGEN` option to show the value that macro variable generates.  That can make the log a little easier to interpret.  But if your macros are complex then using `SYMBOLGEN` can generate so many messages that the logs are again impossible to read.

Answer (score 1):

You have it as title, so you cannot use it for an assignment variable if you are beginner then do use

```
/* this will print in log*/
data _null_;
put "hello world";
run;

/* or use in datastep by making variable or by using macrovariable*/
%let a= Hello World, today is &Sysday, &Sysdate;
data have;
var= "Hello world";
var2= "&a";
run;


proc print data = have;
run;
```